# Delete files in downloads folder that haven't been accessed for more than 30 days

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, cmd.exe

I am looking for a command in notepad (cmd) to delete all files in downloads folder that haven't been accessed for 30 days I have looked about 10+ codes and all were the same, that only delete files that haven't been modified for 30 days.

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d  -30
```

In theory this code works, but instead of deleting files older than 30 days, this command instantly deletes files, even though they were created a few seconds ago.

Comment: Curious, it looks right. If you run `forfiles /S /M *.* /D -30 /C "cmd /c echo @file is at least 30 days old."` does the list of files look about right?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yeah the list is right but like i asked in the question above, it only shows the newly created text document when i change the attribute of modified, and not accessed. I want to delete the files, when the accessed date reaches 30 days.

Comment: I don't think cmd can do this at all. PowerShell may be able to get last access time, but I'm not entirely sure of that either

Comment: @LPChip So why you even answer the question if you are not entirely sure about this....

Comment: I'm not answering, I'm commenting on it.

Comment: Forfiles has a known bug with dates. I often prefer to use `Robocopy` for date matching, you just grab the matched files, wrap it in a simple `FOR /F` Loop and act on it. `FOR /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('robocopy "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads" "C:\DoesntExist" * /NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC /MINAGE:30 /L ') DO @(DEL /Q /F "%_")`

Answer (score 0):

`Forfiles` has known issues with the date, you can work around them, but I dislike that `Forfiles` requires you to instantiate a `cmd` instance to use it, when normally you could work in a for loop, so forfiles is over-all a much slower prospect.

However `Robocopy` does offer a working file selection by a either a number of days or a set date using `/Minage:[n|date]`and `/MaxAge:[n|date]`.
(`/Minage` selects files older than x days/date so that's what you would need)

Here is an example of the command that works for your specific needs if you paste it into the CLI:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('
  robocopy 
    "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads"
     "C:\DoesntExist"
       * 
    /MINAGE:30
    /NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC /L
') DO @(DEL /Q /F "%_")
```

Note I split it into multiple lines to make it easy for you to review and edit it, but it can all be done on one line instead once you understand it.

Now,
If you use it in a CMD/batch Script you would have to amend the loop variable to use a double `%`:

```cmd
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  robocopy 
    "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads"
     "C:\DoesntExist"
       * 
    /MINAGE:30
    /NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC /L
') DO @(DEL /Q /F "%%_")
```

Now a bit about what both of these are doing:

THIS: `"C:\Users\%username%\Downloads"` Is the Path to Delete from.

THIS: `"C:\DoesntExist"` Is  some folder path that does not exist, so nothing can be 'matched', matched files wouldn't be output in results without an extra flag.

THIS: `*` Matches ALL Files regardless of extension, and including those without an extension.

THIS: `/MINAGE:30` Flag selects only files older than 30 days.

THESE: `/NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC` Flags remove excess Info not needed for Deleting the files such as Job header etc.

THIS: `/L` Flag tells Robocopy to LIST the Files only instead of taking any action on them.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this. It moves the files that haven't been accessed for 30 days to a file called ToDelete in the users temp folder and then deletes the ToDelete folder:

```
@echo off
robocopy "%userprofile\downloads" "%temp%\ToDelete" /MinLAD:30 /Mov /e
rd /q /s "%temp%\ToDelete"
```